# ListView Item changing color issue. Multiple items change down the view

Tags: android, listview, listener, listitem

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long   l) {

            if (selectedCourses.contains(courseNames.get(position))){
                selectedCourses.remove(selectedCourses.lastIndexOf(courseNames.get(position)));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                      courseNames.get(position) + " removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .show();

                row = view;
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.charback);

                System.out.println(selectedCourses);
            }

            else{
                selectedCourses.add(courseNames.get(position));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        courseNames.get(position) +" added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                          .show();

                row = view;
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);

                myarrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println(selectedCourses);

            }
```

The selected item turns white, but also about 12 items late another random item turns white just as it comes into view? Can someone please help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long   l) {

        if (selectedCourses.contains(courseNames.get(position))){
            selectedCourses.remove(selectedCourses.lastIndexOf(courseNames.get(position)));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  courseNames.get(position) + " removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                  .show();

            row = view;
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.charback);

            System.out.println(selectedCourses);
        }

        else{
            selectedCourses.add(courseNames.get(position));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    courseNames.get(position) +" added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                      .show();

            row = view;
            row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);

            System.out.println(selectedCourses);

        }
```

I removed myarrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); line....

Answer (score 0):

What will be happening is that your `getView` method in your adapter is not recycling/reusing the `convertView` that is supplied.

If the `convertView` is not null, that means it is a view that is being reused . That means you should explicitly set the background resource to the default, unless the item is selected. The reason you're seeing the white background re-used is because you're *not* resetting the background to the default.

Something like:

```
if (convertView != null) {
   if (selectedCourses.contains(courseNames.get(position))){
       convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
   } else {
       convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.charback);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Holder class for this :

In your adapter class create another **static class that holds your components**: see below code

```
static class MyHolder {

        TextView mTextView;
        RelativeLayout lv;
        ImageView imgInvite;
        RelativeLayout rel_bckground;
    }
```

After that use it in your getView method :

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

           View row = convertView;
            holder = null;

          if (row == null) {

         // initialize your components
         holder = new MyHolder();
         holder.mImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.someID);

        }else{

         holder = (MyHolder) row.getTag();
             }
    }
```